# Defining GRASS region in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am trying to learn GRASS. I have some raster layers and a vector file in  EPSG 32614. Using the grass plugin I  defined a new map set, defined a region using the limits of my raster layers.

[image]

[image]

I succesfully imported both the vectors and the raster in to grass. When I try to run r. cost I have the following error:

> Raster map is in different zone (14) than current region (0)
>
> ￼Unable to open raster map

Nevertheless, the metadada of my raster and vector layers are in  32614 (UTM zone 14N). The grass region settings tool tell me this :

[image]

I looked at  [Raster map in different zone () than region ()](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72913/raster-map-in-different-zone-than-region) but It does not tell how to fix the problem.

I have the same problem working with 2.1 64 bits standalone and also in Lisboa 32 bits standalone working under win 7 64 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using GRASS GIS, you need to understand the notions of LOCATION, MAPSET and REGION ([GRASS GIS: quickstart](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/helptext.html) or [GRASS LOCATION and MAPSET in the QGIS user Manual](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html))

> A LOCATION is defined by its coordinate system, map projection and geographical boundaries...  It is important to understand that each projection stays in its own LOCATION
>
> Each LOCATION can have many MAPSETs. Each MAPSET is a LOCATION's subdirectory.

The REGION is different, it can be seen as a working window for processing rasters (it has nothing to do with a simple zoom function) in a MAPSET (the projection is already fixed in the LOCATION). It can be changed at any time with the GRASS GIS command [g.region](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/g.region.html) or with the GRASS plugin, even if you have defined a default GRASS region:

[image]

Example:

original region (in red):

[image]

after g.region:

[image]